# How are suggested questions generated?

Tags: support

When I go to type a new question in any Stack Exchange site, it automagically suggests 'Questions that may already have your answer'. What technology is this leveraging to generate these results on the fly? Boolean search? Word or doc2vec?

Example:

[image: "Questions that may already have your answer"]

Comment: Did you just imply SO is written in *python???*  Sir, I will have you know it's written in Glorious C#. The nerve.

Comment: Ironic that this question, about a technology to prevent duplicate questions, was itself not saved from becoming a duplicate by that technology #metameta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the site search, the title search on the ask question page is powered by [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).